# How do I make an regular expression that findall text that is in between a and (b or c) in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to make a regular expression where it returns all the occurrence of text that is in between a and first occurence of b or c.

so I tried this code:

```
text = 'dfgahfjbjicij'
re.findall('a(.*?)(b|c)',text)
```

output

```
[('hfj', 'b')]
```

expected:

```
['hfj']
```

How do I make it so the first occurrence is the return not a tuple?

Answer (score 2):

Use a non-capturing group:

```
>>> text = 'dfgahfjbjicij'
>>> re.findall('a(.*?)(b|c)',text)
[('hfj', 'b')]
>>> re.findall('a(.*?)(?:b|c)',text)
['hfj']
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression might work, with lookarounds:

```
(?<=a)(.*?)(?=b|c)
```

or:

```
(?<=a)(.*?)(?=[bc])
```

or:

```
a([^bc]*)[bc]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kxfhcf/1/)

#### Test

```
import re


expression = r"(?<=a)(.*?)(?=b|c)"

string = """

dfgahfjbjicij
dfgahfjjicij

"""

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['hfj', 'hfjji']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SIyVkW/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/SIyVkW/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]